# When launching maven, showing an error testng.xml is not valid file

Tags: selenium

http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    4.0.0
    DataDriven
    Udemy
    0.0.1-SNAPSHOT

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.relevantcodes/extentreports -->
<dependencies>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.relevantcodes/extentreports -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.relevantcodes</groupId>
        <artifactId>extentreports</artifactId>
        <version>2.41.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>3.11.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.uncommons/reportng -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.uncommons</groupId>
        <artifactId>reportng</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.inject/guice -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.inject</groupId>
        <artifactId>guice</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.0</version>
    </dependency>



    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.sun.mail/javax.mail -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.mail</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.mail</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>6.0.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
        <version>3.17</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi-ooxml -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
        <version>3.17</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/dom4j/dom4j -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>dom4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.poi/poi-ooxml-schemas -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi-ooxml-schemas</artifactId>
        <version>3.17</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.xmlbeans/xmlbeans -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.xmlbeans</groupId>
        <artifactId>xmlbeans</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-io/commons-io -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>2.6</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
        <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
        <version>6.9.10</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

     <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.surefire</groupId>
    <artifactId>surefire-testng</artifactId>
    <version>2.18.1</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
<build>
<pluginManagement>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>2.18.1</version>
       <configuration>
    <suiteXmlFiles>
      <suiteXmlFile>src/test/resources/runner/testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>
    </suiteXmlFiles>
  </configuration>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</pluginManagement>
```

Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.18.1:test (default-test) on project Udemy: Execution default-test of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.18.1:test failed: There was an error in the forked process
[ERROR] org.apache.maven.surefire.testset.TestSetFailedException: Suite file E:\Udemy\Udemy\src\test\resources\runner\testng.xml is not a valid file
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGXmlTestSuite.locateTestSets(TestNGXmlTestSuite.java:116)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.surefire.testng.TestNGProvider.invoke(TestNGProvider.java:83)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.invokeProviderInSameClassLoader(ForkedBooter.java:203)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.runSuitesInProcess(ForkedBooter.java:155)
[ERROR] at org.apache.maven.surefire.booter.ForkedBooter.main(ForkedBooter.java:103)
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginExecutionException

Answer (score 2):

just update you plugin with this

```
     <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.20</version>
            <configuration>
                <suiteXmlFiles>
                 <suiteXmlFile>src/test/resources/runner/testng.xml</suiteXmlFile>
                </suiteXmlFiles>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

Comment: Thanks. Is this better than the above approach ? Surefire does not log the test names to console. Should I use listeners or loggers to do the logging ?

Comment: yes you can use listener for the same , you can create a class which will implement ITestListener and you can add all Override classes and in OnTestStart you can do this

Comment: @Override
  public void onTestStart(ITestResult result) {
    LOG.info("#####Test {}.{}() Started#####", result.getInstanceName(), result.getMethod().getMethodName());
  }

Comment: Similarly on TestSucess @Override
  public void onTestSuccess(ITestResult result) {
    LOG.info("#####Test {}.{}() Completed Successfully#####", result.getInstanceName(),
        result.getMethod().getMethodName());

  }

Answer (score 2):

```
 <properties>
    <testng.files.location>src/test/resources/</testng.files.location>
    <testng.file>testng.xml</testng.file>
    <maven-surefire.version>2.20</maven-surefire.version>
    <org.aspectj-version>1.6.10</org.aspectj-version>
    <aspectj.version>1.8.10</aspectj.version>
    <testng.version>6.14.2</testng.version>
</properties>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${maven-surefire.version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <suiteXmlFiles>
                    <suiteXmlFile>${testng.files.location}${testng.file}</suiteXmlFile>
                </suiteXmlFiles>

            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>

</build>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.relevantcodes</groupId>
        <artifactId>extentreports</artifactId>
        <version>2.41.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>3.11.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.inject</groupId>
        <artifactId>guice</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.mail</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.mail</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>6.0.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
        <version>3.17</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
        <version>3.17</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>dom4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi-ooxml-schemas</artifactId>
        <version>3.17</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.xmlbeans</groupId>
        <artifactId>xmlbeans</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
        <version>2.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
        <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
        <version>6.9.10</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
        <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
        <version>${testng.version}</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: How do we set the value of these variables ? ${testng.files.location}${testng.file}

Comment: you have to provide the values for ${testng.files.location}${testng.file}  in <properties> </properties> section as i have  given above

Answer (score 0):

If you have already added the `testng.xml` file in the project directory and tests are passing locally, then edit your auto generated `.gitignore` file and remove `TEST**.xml` from that then push the code and rerun the build.